# Python Bokeh scope of functions

Tags: python

There one thing i don't understand with `Bokeh` (and I think `Matplotlib` has a similar behavior):

It seems that if functions perform actions over the `figure`, it doesn't matter whether the `figure` has been passed as an argument or returned. The local / global scope barrier seems not apply. 
For instance:

```
p = figure(plot_width=400, height=400)
d= pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,2), columns = ['x', 'y']) 

def add_circles():
    p.circle(x=d['x'], y=d['y'], color='black', size=5)

add_circles()
show(p)
```

This piece of code will show the circles being rendered on the charts, while they have been created inside the function `add_cirles`, and not returned. Additionaly neither the figure `p` nor the DataFrame `d` has been passed to the function.

Why is it so?
And what is the best practice in that case? Pass/return the `figure` in arguments and return statements, or let it as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to bokeh or matplotlib.
You don't need to return/pass anything becasue you are using a function in the function. If p = figure(), as soon as you do p.circle() it will add the glyphrenderer to that figure.

it behaves like

```
a=3
b=[]

def test():
    b.append(a)

test()
b
```

it works with the function append, but not with +=

```
a=3
b=[]

def test():
    b+=[a]

test()
b
```

You don't need to return anything because your function add_circles() is just doing whatever .circle() is doing. And you don't need to pass p because functions already know about variables declared outside:

```
a = 5

def test():
    c = a + 2
    print c

test()
```

It's just bad practice because you write a function that is supposed to be general/re-usable while using specific variable names.

Comment: Thank you very much; Where can I find more info about that behavior in the python documentation? I have been looking in a reference book about local and global scope for that, but didn't find anything regarding the behavior you are explaining.

Comment: Especially now that I realised that if I put that function in a module, then I will need to pass `p` and `d` as args! Yet still `p` doesn't need to be returned! Sorry it might be obvious for you!

Comment: I edited my answer to expand on why you don't need to pass p. But you should if you want to ever re-use that function in different codes. Sorry I don't know links to detailed explanation on this

Comment: That's fine, thx anyway. What about the return statement? Would you say it's best to have it or not have it?

Comment: your add_circles() is just doing what p.circle() is doing, so you could do a = add_circles() and it would do the same thing as a = p.circles()